# ApolloConsumer VS import client

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

Why should I use ApolloConsumer instead of importing directly the client in my module ?

From the doc I should do somthing like :

```
// Module A.js initiate client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  // init cache, links, typeDefs...
});
export default client;
```

```js
// Module index.jsx
import client from 'A';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>, 
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```js
// Any other component not using Query or Mutation
const Other = () => (
  <ApolloConsumer>
  {
    client => {
      // use client
    }
  }
  </ApolloConsumer>);
```

But why not just import client without ApolloConsumer ?

```
// Module OtherBis
import client from 'A';

const AltOther () => {
  // do something with client
  return <div></div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably for the same reasons why you shouldn't import `store` directly:

> Similarly, while you can reference your store instance by importing it directly, this is not a recommended pattern in Redux. If you create a store instance and export it from a module, it will become a singleton. This means it will be harder to isolate a Redux app as a component of a larger app, if this is ever necessary, or to enable server rendering, because on the server you want to create separate store instances for every request.

Comment: I'm not using SSR and i'm working on a sole SPA so I should be fine ? Also isn't creating a client a startup and passing it to the App component a singleton already ?

Comment: @Yvain yes, it is. In SSR scenarios `createStore` function is imported instead of `store` and the function is run for each request so that each request gets its own `store`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `ApolloConsumer` component is created for support `JSX` just like `react-relay` for `relay`. It is not necessary. Actually I have never used the `ApolloConsumer`. Moreover there are hooks(eg. `useQuery`, `useMutation`, `useSubscription`) which can do everything. They just make a tool. Whether use it or not is up to you.